# Excel UDF Filter Range

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, user-defined-functions

I have a function that takes a range of values as input (just a column) as well as some threshold. I would like to return a range that is filtered to include all values from the original range that are greater than the threshold. I have the following code:

```
Public Function FilterGreaterThan(Rng As Range, Limit As Double) As Range

Dim Cell As Range
Dim ResultRange As Range

For Each Cell In Rng
    If Abs(Cell.Value) >= Limit Then
        If ResultRange Is Nothing Then
            Set ResultRange = Cell
        Else
            Set ResultRange = Union(ResultRange, Cell)
        End If
    End If    
Next
Set FilterGreaterThan = ResultRange
End Function
```

The issue is that once a number is below the threshold, other numbers after that one that are above the threshold do not get added to the range.

For example:

```
Threshold - 2

Numbers -

3
4
1
5
```

It will loop through adding 3 and 4 but 5 will not be added. I end up getting a #value error. But I get no error and it works fine if I only enter the range - 3, 4 or the range - 3, 4, 1.

Comment: Hi, you're function works fine if you put it inside another function like =SUM(FilterGreaterThan(A1:A7,2)).  The problem I think you're having is that you're putting =FilterGreaterThan(A1:A7,2) in a cell and when it returns a multi-area range, you get a #VALUE! error.  Even still, I don't understand the result that comes back from =FilterGreaterThan(A1:A7,2) anyway since you are just getting back a (what seems to be) random number from the range.

Comment: If you add `Debug.Print FilterGreaterThan.Address` just before End Function, you can see the range address of the function. It looks like UDF's perhaps don't like non-contiguous ranges.

Answer (score 2):

It's looks like the UDF doesn't like non-contiguous ranges being written back to an array.

One way around it is to re-write the UDF like below. It assumes the output array is only in column but does allow multiple column input.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function FilterGreaterThan(Rng As Range, Limit As Double) As Variant

Dim Cell As Range
Dim WriteArray() As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim cellVal As Variant
Dim CountLimit As Long

CountLimit = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, ">=" & Limit)
ReDim WriteArray(1 To CountLimit, 1 To 1) 'change if more than 1 column
For Each Cell In Rng

    cellVal = Cell.Value
    If Abs(cellVal) >= Limit Then
            i = i + 1 'change if more than 1 column
            WriteArray(i, 1) = cellVal 'change if more than 1 column
    End If
Next
FilterGreaterThan = WriteArray
End Function
```

Comment: +1 although if `CountLimit` is 0 then it will just return `#VALUE!` (instead of `#N/A`) if called as a UDF. If called from VBA then you would get a "Subscript out of range" error if `CountLimit` is 0

Comment: Your right, there's no error handling and assumes CountLimit>0.

Comment: I just looked at the code. It seems that the 
CountLimit = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, ">=" & Limit) doesn't take into account the absolute value consideration. Not sure where to add that though

Comment: I was trying to be sneaky and get the value of the array but forgot about ABS! :)

Comment: That ABS is a slippery little sucker :)

Answer (score 2):

ooo got there first but I've typed it out now so I may as well post it. This version will return as a column vector of the correct size.

If nothing matches then #N/A is returned in a 1 by 1 array (this is consistent with the normal behaviour of an array function when there are insufficient values to fill the array)

*edit2: updated function thanks to comments from ooo*

```
Public Function FilterGreaterThan(Rng As Range, Limit As Double) As Variant()

Dim inputCell As Range ' each cell we read from
Dim resultCount As Integer ' number of matching cells found
Dim resultValue() As Variant ' array of cell values

resultCount = 0
ReDim resultValue(1 To 1, 1 To Rng.Cells.Count)

For Each inputCell In Rng
    If Abs(inputCell.Value) >= Limit Then
        resultCount = resultCount + 1
        resultValue(1, resultCount) = inputCell.Value
    End If
Next inputCell

' Output array must be two-dimensional and we can only
' ReDim Preserve the last dimension
If (resultCount > 0) Then
    ReDim Preserve resultValue(1 To 1, 1 To resultCount)
Else
    resultValue(1, 1) = CVErr(xlErrNA)
    ReDim Preserve resultValue(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
End If

' Transpose the results to produce a column rather than a row
resultValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(resultValue)

FilterGreaterThan = resultValue

End Function
```

---

edit: works OK for me with the test values in the comment below:

[image: Excel file showing FilterGreaterThan UDF working correctly]

I'm sure you know this but don't include the `{` or `}` characters when entering the array formula - Excel adds them in after you've hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, I continue to get a #value error with your code. Any thoughts? Example I am using:

Rng values to filter: -0.003742158,0.004134996,-0.002937923
Limit: 0.0008

Comment: Yours is the right answer. The only change I'd make is Dim the array to full size at start and `ReDim Preserve resultValue(1 To 1, 1 To resultCount)` once only at the end before transpose - you've got the max array size with `rng.cells.count`. Also, both of ours treat resultValue as a value rather than array if only 1 cell :)

Comment: @ooo thanks - I've updated my answer to incorporate these suggestions