# Add in or VBA script to add filter command to excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Google sheets has a filter command with the syntax

```
=filter(Range, criteria 1, ... criteria n)
```

It returns an array.

How can I do this in excel?

Example:  I have a range 2 columns wide, with Genus in column 1, and the full botanical name in column 2.  This range is named bot_name

Elsewhere I have a cell C1 with "Abies", the genus name for the firs.

In Google spreadsheet I can do this:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(Bot_Name,REGEXMATCH(Bot_Name,C1)))
```

For each row in the range, FILTER includes it if REGEXMATCH returns true.

Filter and Unique are filter functions.

Filter is documented:
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197

From this I should get the following list:

```
   Abies balsamea
   Abies concolor
   Abies lasiocarpa var bifolia
   Abies veitch
```

Comment: In Excel there are array formulas as well as filters and advanced filters. Could you provide some specific information (including cell references) together with sample data and the expected results?

Comment: You could write UDF's in VBA to replicate the Google Sheets functions. Would this be of interest?

Comment: I see, so you in fact do not need to mimic the FILTER function at all, you just need to list unique values that meet certain condition.

Comment: VDohnal, Isn't that what a filter is -- a method of returning a subset of a dataset?   I suspect we have different concepts of what a filter is.

Comment: @SherwoodBotsford Completely re-written the answer, since your problem is different from what I thought.

Comment: @chrisneilsen Yes.  I assume UDF = User Defined Functions.  Yes I'm interested.  Can these be written in a general way?  I'm surprised there isn't a whole pool of UDF's out there somewhere.  Or have I just not yet used the right search terms.

Comment: Here's [one example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12397069/445425) of a Filter like UDF.  It's not general enough for your case, but might get you started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you use formulas and not the Excel filter feature (which is very different from `FILTER` function you have mentioned), because I suppose you need that your filtered data change whenever you change the search expression (e.g. Abies).

First you need to check which values match your criteria:

I suggest that you use `COUNTIF` function - it enables you to use wildcards in your search expression - I add * at the end to find everything that starts with "Abies".

So formula in a helper column looks like this:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A2,$C$2 & "*")>0,A2,"")
```

You can hide the helper column later.
Then you need to remove duplicates - so the next final formula will be a non-array formula:

```
=INDEX($D$2:$D$15,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($E$1:E1,$D$2:$D$15),0,0),0))
```

Your sheet would now look like this with search expression in the cell C2:

[image]

Also use IFERROR to remove cells having error. Also you can use named ranges instead of `$D$2:$D$15` to simplify the second formula.

[Download the sample Excel sheet here.](http://www.filedropper.com/plantsfilter)

This is more complicated than using FILTER function with array and I really miss this feature in Excel.

Comment: You get +1 from me for a solid informative answer.  You are correct that Filter in Excel doesn't meet my needs.  It isn't a function taht you can call in a formula.  ***  The other two answers make my eyes hurt.  It will take me a bit to figure out what they are doing.

Comment: Notice to other readers: You DO need to download the example to make sense of this.  POZVYHLEDAT = Match. ; may be comma depending on your local.

Comment: The long term purpose of this is to get a series of cascading drop boxes that are dependent on previous choices, WITHOUT having to create a zillion named ranges.  This is a good technique, and a fabulous answer, so I will leave it.  I will use this to understand it, then will write a new question with this addtional requirement, makeing reference to this solution.

Comment: Yes, thanks, it is quite frustrating translating excel formulas. But I wrote it in the text and when you open the sample file in your language, it should be ok.

Comment: One thing that is NOT obvious:  The internal COUNTIF returns a RANGE -- acts as an array formula, returning a sequence of 1;0;1... when given two ranges as parameters.  This range has zeros where the corresponding entry in column D is non blank.   I've yet to find clear documentation on this.  In passing:  Excel needs a better way to enter big formulas and seeing intermediate results.  This single line program and F9 debugging reminds me of BASIC spaghetti code goto's